Merge Multiple Pages of a PDF File into a Single Page in JavaScript
I have pdfs of varying size. They are multiple pages long. I need them to be one page for processing. I cannot figure out how to make it so I get a pdf output of just one really long page where all the data from the pages is there.
I tried using PDF.js, pdf-lib, turning the pdf into images and then into a pdf file again. I cant figure out how to do it and I can't find documentation on it. It needs to be in JS unfortunately. I found an implementation for Python using Spire. I can't do this unfortunately.

That's unfortunate to hear. To be honest I have little idea of what I'm doing. I'm doing a NodeJS project. I need to scan PDFs but they need to be 1 page. I suppose I can try and get my python implementation working. I'll try to figure out how to call a python script then in the python script tell the NodeJS that it's done procesing? Thanks for letting me know though.
